# Логирование SOAP Запросов в Glassfish v4

Tags: java, oracle, soap, glassfish

Возникла проблема: требуется отлавливать SOAP-Запросы, которые будут уходить через приложение в GlassFish. Нашёл, как включить логирование SOAP-запросов в GlassFish v3 и v2, но вот с 4-ой версией возникли проблемы. Официальную документацию пробовал читать, но не помогло...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю на счет средств именно гласфиша. Но можно написать хендлер для логирования, должно везде роботать:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPException;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;

public class LogMessageHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    ...

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return Collections.EMPTY_SET;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        logMessage(context);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext context) {
    }

    private void logMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        if (!log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            return;
        }
        Boolean isRequest = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
        SOAPMessage msg = context.getMessage();
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            msg.writeTo(out);
            String strMsg = new String(out.toByteArray());
            log.info((isRequest ? "Request: " : "Response: ") + strMsg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception while logging soap message: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

потом этот хендлер нужно прицепить к клиенту:

```
List<Handler> handlers = ((BindingProvider) port).getBinding().getHandlerChain();
handlers.add(new LogMessageHandler());
((BindingProvider) port).getBinding().setHandlerChain(handlers); //обязательно так
```